# Assign new value in DataFrame column based on group max

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a data frame and I'd like to add a new column based the value in two columns, where one uses the group max. For example, here's an example `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['a'] * 2 + ['b'] * 4,
                   "col2": [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   "col3": ['yep', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yep', 'yep']})


df
  col1  col2 col3
0    a     1  yep
1    a     2   no
2    b     1   no
3    b     2   no
4    b     3  yep
5    b     4  yep
```

Now, what I'd like is a new column that said "yes" where `col2` is the group max, grouping on `col1` and `col3` is equal to "yep".

```
  col1  col2 col3 col4
0    a     1  yep  no
1    a     2   no  no
2    b     1   no  no
3    b     2   no  no
4    b     3  yep  no
5    b     4  yep  yes
```

I've tried the code below, but I'm getting a slight error on the return value:

```
# define function
def max_bal(df):
    max_row = df['col2'].max()
    label = np.where((df['col3'] == 'yep') & 
                     (df['col2'] == max_row),
                     'Yes', 
                     'No')
    return label
```

Now call function in a group by statement

```
df.groupby('col1').apply(max_bal)

col1
a             [No, No]
b    [No, No, No, Yes]
dtype: object
```

These are the correct values but not returned in a `Series` as I would expect. I'd need one `Series`/`array`/`list` because I'm trying to assign the these values to a new column in the `df` above (see `col4'). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return `labels` as a DataFrame with the same index as the group the function is being applied on.

```
def max_bal(df):
    max_row = df['col2'].max()
    labels = np.where((df['col3'] == 'yep') & 
                     (df['col2'] == max_row),
                     'Yes', 
                     'No')
    return pd.DataFrame(labels, index=df.index)

df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1').apply(max_bal)
```

Comment: This works, but why? I'm learning Python/pandas, and I'm trying to bridge the gap between my initial attempt and the DataFrame solution with the original DataFrame index specified.