# Pandas (python): max in columns define new value in new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, max, apply

I have a df with about 50 columns:

```
Product ID | Cat1 | Cat2 |Cat3 | ... other columns ...
8937456       0      5     10
8497534       25     3     0
8754392       4      15    7
```

Cat signifies how many quantities of that product fell into a category. Now I want to add a column "Category" denoting the majority Category for a product (ignoring the other columns and just considering the Cat columns).

df_goal:

```
Product ID | Cat1 | Cat2 |Cat3 | Category | ... other columns ...
8937456       0      5     10       3
8497534       25     3     0        1
8754392       4      15    7        2
```

I think I need to use max and apply or map?

I found those on stackoverflow, but they don't not address the category assignment. In Excel I renamed the columns from Cat 1 to 1 and used index(match(max)).

[Python Pandas max value of selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033111/python-pandas-max-value-of-selected-columns)

[How should I take the max of 2 columns in a dataframe and make it another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169170/how-should-i-take-the-max-of-2-columns-in-a-dataframe-and-make-it-another-column)

[Assign new value in DataFrame column based on group max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149726/assign-new-value-in-dataframe-column-based-on-group-max)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a NumPy way with [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) -

```
df['Category'] = df.values[:,1:].argmax(1)+1
```

To restrict the selection to those columns, use those column headers/names specifically and then use `idxmax` and finally replace the string `Cat` with `empty strings, like so -

```
df['Category'] = df[['Cat1','Cat2','Cat3']].idxmax(1).str.replace('Cat','')
```

`numpy.argmax` or `panda's idxmax` basically gets us the ID of max element along an axis.

If we know that the column names for the `Cat` columns start at `1st` column and end at `4th` one, we can *slice* the dataframe : `df.iloc[:,1:4]` instead of `df[['Cat1','Cat2','Cat3']]`.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply; can I ask, how argmax works? I unfortunately have other columns in the df as well; is there a way to restrict it to those columns or should I save the required columns as its own df?

Comment: Select those columns then use `.values`.

Comment: uhhh! brilliant! testing

Comment: df['Category'] = df[['Cat1','Cat2','Cat3']].idxmax(1).str.replace('Cat','') worked perfectly; amazing one liner; thank you - wish I could give it more than one vote